# spring security AuthenticationManager vs AuthenticationProvider?

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

Can someone tell me the difference between an `AuthenticationManager` and an `AuthenticationProvider` in Spring Security?

How are they used and how are they called. It is my understanding that a `SecurityFilter` will call the `AuthenticationManager` to authenticate an `Authentication` object? But then where does the `AuthenticationProvider` come into play?

Thanks!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I think the `AuthenticationManager` delegates the fetching of persistent user information to one or more `AuthenticationProvider`s. The authentication-providers (`DaoAuthenticationProvider, JaasAuthenticationProvider, LdapAuthenticationProvider, OpenIDAuthenticationProvider` for example) specialize in accessing specific user-info repositories.
Something else is mentioned in [this part](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-auth-manager) of the reference manual. It says:

*You may want to register additional AuthenticationProvider  beans with the ProviderManager and you can do this using the  element with the ref  attribute, where the value of the attribute is the name of the provider bean you want to add.*

In other words, you can specify multiple AuthenticationProviders, for example one that looks for users in an LDAP database and another that looks in an SQL database.

Comment: So, you would very rarely need to implement a AuthenticationManager, but rather you would just implement AuthenticationProviders to fetch the user details from wherever you want to obtain them from?

Comment: Most of the AuthenticationProviders that you could need have already been written by the guys that write Spring Security, and are right there in the API documentation so you can configure them. 

If the one you need is not in the framework yet, it's probably trivial to implement the AuthenticationProvider interface for your purposes.

Comment: As Hans said,
In Sprint Security, The class ProviderManager is an implementation of AuthenticationManager, which calls authenticate method AuthenticationProvider.
The method signature of that Provider Manager is 
org.springframework.security.providers.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(Authentication)

Comment: do you know some link with a example of implementation for a custom AuthenticationManager? I am trying implement a simple case for be my base for a more complex one, but I can't figure out what I should execute in this class. I already have one AuthenticationProvider for retrieve the user data from database.

Comment: Why there is no `AuthenticationProvider` in spring security webflux?

Answer (score 40):

Both AuthenticationManager and AuthenticationProvider are interfaces. They have different functionalities in the Spring Security Flow.

Ref-
**[Spring Boot + Spring Security Architecture](https://www.javainuse.com/webseries/spring-security-jwt/chap3)**

[image]

**AuthenticationManager** - When user tries to access an application, the http request is intercepted by filter/filter chain. Using the Authentication Object created the filter will then call the authenticate method of the Authentication Manager. The Authentication Manager is only a interface and actual implementation of the authenticate method is provided by the ProviderManager.The ProviderManager has a list of AuthenticationProviders. From it's authenticate method it calls the authenticate method of the appropriate AuthenticateProvider. In response it gets the Principal Authentication Object if the authentication is successful.

[image]

**AuthenticationProvider -** The AuthenicationProvider is an interface with an authenticate and a supports method. It has various implementations like CasAuthenticationProvider or DaoAuthenticationProvider. Depending on the implementation an appropriate AuthenicationProvider implementation is used. It is in the AuthenticationProvider implementation authenticate method where all the actual authentication takes place.

[image]

Comment: Gr8 flow +1.  `Using the Authentication Object created ` where and how is this object created. And what details does this object have. Can we create it explicitly?

Comment: @Rehan, u should edit this response and add supports method under auth provider interface.

Answer (score 17):

From spring [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#core-services-authentication-manager)

> The `AuthenticationManager` is just an interface, so the implementation can be anything we choose
>
> The default implementation in Spring Security is called `ProviderManager` and rather than handling the authentication request itself, it delegates to a list of configured `AuthenticationProvider` s, each of which is queried in turn to see if it can perform the authentication. Each provider will either throw an exception or return a fully populated `Authentication` object.

Also if you check the source code for `AuthenticationManager`, `ProviderManager` and `AuthenticationProvider` you can see this clearly.

`ProviderManager` implements the `AuthenticationManager` interface and it has list of AuthenticationProviders. So if you want to have custom authentication mechanism, you'll need to implement new `AuthenticationProvider`.

Comment: similarly, what is the default implementation of `AuthenticationProvider`