# Difference in AuthenticationManager and AuthenticationProvider Authenticate method in Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Is there any difference in

```
Authentication auth= authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);
```

and

```
 Authentication auth= authenticationProvider.authenticate(authentication);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spring security AuthenticationManager vs AuthenticationProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323377/spring-security-authenticationmanager-vs-authenticationprovider)

Answer (score 16):

`AuthenticationManager` holds list of `AuthenticationProvider` instances.

When you execute `authenticationManager.authenticate()`

What this actually does is iterate over all instances of `AuthenticationProvider` and tries to authenticate user with each one.

Default spring implementation of `AuthenticationManager` is `org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager`

The actual authentication is performed inside AuthenticationProvider.
Each `AuthenticationProvider` contains instance of `UserDetailsService` which is responsible for fetching user information (including hashed password) out of database for example, or LDAP. Once instance of `UserDetails` is successfully retrieved from database 
`AuthenticationProvider` will then use instance of `PasswordEncoder` to check whether password user provided matches hashed password you retrieved from database.

more info here http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/providers/ProviderManager.html

and here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.html